# How to subset a list of a list based on the name

Tags: r, list, subset

I am given a list of lists.
I would like now to subset the list based on the names of the sublist.

```
 L1<-list("A"=matrix(c(1:4),2),"B"=matrix(c("a","b","c","d"),2))
 L2<-list("A"=matrix(c(5:8),2),"B"=matrix(c("u","v","w","x"),2))
 L<-list(L1,L2)
```

I would now like to select the elements of the sublist according to their name. E.g.

```
select_names <- c("A")
```

and obtain a list of lists, whereas the sublist now only contains the elements that have names belonging to 'select_names'. In this case it would be just the element "A":

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$`A`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4


[[2]]
[[2]]$`A`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `Extract`

```
library(purrr)
map(L, `[`, select_names)
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$A
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4


#[[2]]
#[[2]]$A
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    5    7
#[2,]    6    8
```

---

Or using `lapply`

```
lapply(L, function(x) x[select_names])
```

Or without anonymous function call

```
lapply(L, `[`, select_names)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Self promotion.** If one is open to using packages, I wrote up a convenience function in the developer version of [manymodelr](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/manymodelr/tree/develop) that achieves the same.

```
manymodelr::get_this(A,L)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which also works pefectly fine. Yet, I prefer to use no extra packages. That's why I accepted akrun's answer, as I already use purrr resp. tidyverse.

Comment: No worries, glad you got an answer.